# Regex - Creating validation to enforce that a string has 2+ words

Tags: regex

If you have a moment, I need some help adding to my regex expression. I am validating a response in a Google Form for the user's full name.

The validation requires:

1. That only letters are used
2. That the user inputs both the first and second name (at a minimum), separated by a space

So far I have come up with:

[a-zA-Z ]+]

But this lacks the check for a minimum of two words in a given string.

After an hour of fails and googling, I have admitted defeat and need your help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: `^[a-zA-Z]{2,}(?: [a-zA-Z]{2,})+$`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2NTbfn/1/).

Comment: The above regex reads, "match two or more letters (`{2,}`) at the beginning of the line (`^`) followed by a non-capture group (`(?: [a-zA-Z]{2,})`) that is matched one or more times (`+`), followed by the end of the line ('$'), where the non-capture group matches a space followed by two or more letters (`[a-zA-Z]{2,}`).

Comment: Thank you Cary, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:
`/^[a-z]{2,}( [a-z]+)*?( [a-z]{2,}){1,}$/i`

It matches:

- john smith ◄ all lowercase
- John Smith
- John P E Smith
- John Paul E Smith
- John Paul Eward Smith

It ignores:

- John
- John S
- John Paul S
- John Paul Edward S
- J0hn Smith  ◄ zero instead of the letter 'o'
- John     Smith  ◄ multiple spaces

You can play with [this fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/R1Z1Yj/2).

Best regards

Comment: Thank you Eric, exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Toby, I simplified the regex, but the result remains the same.